# replace both thermostat element; My wires incoming are 220/240 but is 120 volt tank

Tags: electrical

Can I replace both thermostat  element on electric water heater? My wires incoming are 220/240 but my water heater is 120 volt tank; In need of help to know if I can do this safely.Thank to all of those whom could help in a seriously bad situation

Comment: Bad situation or not, I don't understand what you mean.   It surely can be done, but we need more to know whether to tell you to do A,B,C or D,E,F.  The "wires incoming" are 220/240, that's fairly typical for a house.  "Water heater is a 120V tank" that might mean a 120V water heater, but those are *rather extremely small*, nobody would put that in a house. What makes you use that term?  **Is is a natural gas heater?**  Can you shoot a photo of the informational nameplate on the water heater?

Comment: What make and model is the new water heater?